# Sending HTTP Requests to API from Razor Pages App

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am creating an application that presents users with a form. When the user submits the form, my application takes those values and formats them into a query string. This string is then used to make a call to a third party API. The application is written in C# using an ASP.NET Core Razor Pages template in Visual Studio 2019. I had first experimented with creating an HTTPClient and sending an HTTPRequestMessage to the third party API using hard-coded values in a console app, which worked perfectly. However, when moving my code into a Razor Pages application to add a front end for the app I can't seem to get the application to call the code I created. Since I am only taking form values and passing them in a query string to a third-party API, which doesn't require me to define my own model, I decided to use Razor Pages instead of ASP.NET MVC.

This is the Index.cshtml page as I set it up in my application:

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}

    <div>
        <form asp-page-handler="ProcessRequest" method="post">
            <label for="FirstName">First Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="FirstName" value="" />
            <label for="LastName">Last Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="LastName" value="" />
            <label for="Email">Email:</label>
            <input type="text" name="Email" value="" />
            <button type="submit">Send Request</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

As you can see, it is just a simple form with three input fields, nothing fancy.

The underlying Index.cshtml.cs file containing the model logic has the following code:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    static HttpClient myAppHTTPClient = new HttpClient();

    public async void OnPostProcessRequestAsync()
    {            
        string firstName, lastName, email;
        string host = "https://thirdparty.app.com:443/";
        string pathname = "path/to/api/endpoint/?operation=create";

        firstName = "Test";
        LastName = "User";
        email = "TestUser@email.com";

        string path = pathname + "&first_name=" + firstName + "&last_name=" + lastName + "&email=" + email;
        string requestUrl = host + path;

        HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage();

        try
        {
            HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await myAppHTTPClient.PostAsync(requestUrl, httpRequestMessage.Content);
            HttpContent content = responseMessage.Content;
            string message = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Console.WriteLine("The output from thirdparty is: {0}", message);
            RedirectToPage();
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("An HTTP request exception occurred. {0}", exception.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

The documentation for ASP.NET Razor Pages says that when you have an asp-page-handler tag helper in your form submitting the form will call the page handler method `OnPost[method_name]Async()`. In my case, the line `<form asp-page-handler="ProcessRequest" method="post">` in the form should call the `public async void OnPostProcessRequestAsync()` method. However, this isn't working as I thought it would. I tried using different tag helpers in the form and in the submit button. Is there a way to get the Razor Page to call the method that runs my code. I know I am missing the RedirectToPage() method but I first want to get the method call to work.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Razor pages but an async method should return a Task/Task<T>, void should only be returned in case of async event handlers.

Comment: Yeah, I am not too clear on how a Razor pages app differs from an MVC app. Now that you mentioned it, I did notice how the OnPostAsync() methods in the documentation examples return a Task<IActionResult>. Not sure what a Task<IActionResult> is or how I am supposed to return it. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by not working ? the function isn't fired when clicking the submit button ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean by not working.

Comment: I tried to recreate it by basically copy pasting your code (fixing the typo of Lastname, should be lower case) and including some random url to Post to, but I can't reproduce your behavior. When I submit the form and set a breakpoint in the OnPostProcessRequestAsync method it's invoked just as expected.

Comment: Add a `return` statement before `RedirectToPage()` and change the handler to return a `Task<IActionResult>`, not `void`. You will also need to `return` from the `catch` block. And `Console.WriteLine` is pointless in an ASP.NET app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though two people on this thread already suggested the answer, I didn't see a way where I could mark their comments as having answered the question. So, to be fair and give credit where credit is due, their suggestions allowed me to fix my code. Basically, I had defined the page handler method incorrectly. I had defined it as:

```
public async void OnPostProcessRequestAsync()...
```

However, this type of application requires page handler methods to return something like Task. When changing the return type from void to Task this worked perfectly. My guess is that since I am defining this code asynchronously, the return value must be something asynchronous. Since the Task<> class is used for Threading (async) code it makes sense that this would work.

Comment: The httpClient request works well in the console app, but it fails on razor pages. I got an error: "System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception." Actually, it fails on production web server, it works well on my local pc. I am using net core 5. Did you get this error message as well? or you have a sample, or can you guide me where to get a sample for razor pages? thanks.

Comment: Do you have a sample of the code your using to make requests using the client?